# js (vanilla) - drop image on element 1 and handle the drop in default file uploader

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drop an image on image box - but using the drop event I already created for typical file uploader (prevent code duplication).
I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="Btn" class="btn2">
    <input id="FileUpl" type="file" style="display:none;">
    <img class="fill">
</div>
```

And the following JS:

```
let Btn=document.getElementById("Btn");
let FileUpl=document.getElementById("FileUpl"); 

Btn.addEventListener("drop",Go);

function Go(e) { FileUpl.ondrop(e); } // SEE NOTES BELOW
```

**NOTES**
The "FileUpl" originally is generated by a function, which attaches to it special handling of dropped file.
Hence: I prefer to not duplicate my code there to run in Btn, but to trigger the ondrop event there.
However: Seems nothing is being calling...

The drop event passes to FileUpl.ondrop, but somehow is not being processing.
While if I would drop directly on FileUpl control (if it would be stand alone one), then it would process the file on drop without any problem.

**My question:** What is the right way to trigger the handler I have in the control FileUpl...?
I am using Vanilla JS (no library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action for `dragenter`, `dragexit`, and `dragover` events, After that you can handle the dropbox with `drop` event like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    
    <style>
        .drop-section {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .drop-section > * {
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            min-width: 450px;
            min-height: 450px;
            padding: 30px;
            line-height: 450px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="drop-section">
        <div class="drop-section__area">
            Drop your image here!
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <script>
        let dropArea = document.querySelector(".drop-section__area");

        // preventDefault and stopPropagation with some style
        function dragHandler(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dropArea.style.background = "#f9f9f9";
            dropArea.style.opacity = ".5";
        };

        dropArea.addEventListener("dragenter", dragHandler);
        dropArea.addEventListener("dragexit", dragHandler);
        dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", dragHandler);

        // handle the drop event
        function drop(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            dropArea.style.background = "unset";
            dropArea.style.opacity = "1";
            var [file] = e.dataTransfer.files;
            console.log(file.name);
        };

        dropArea.addEventListener("drop", drop);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Read more about `DataTransfer` from [here](https://mzl.la/3nC991X)